# sendmail rule to rewrite recipient only for specific {client_addr}... how?

Tags: sendmail

For any incoming email from one particular IP address, I am accepting it, but I also want to re-write the (envelope) recipient eg:

if ${client_addr}='12.34.56.78' then append ".custom.local" on the end:

eg:

recipient@example.com becomes recipient@example.com.custom.local

I want to do this as early as I can, so normal rule processing continues (in particular, the mailertable feature)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Is it even possible to use the ${client_addr} macro on the left side of an "R" rule together with (to match) a literal IP address in a .cf file ?

Answer (score 1):

This might save other peeps the entire day of lost productivity I wasted getting this right...  beware the tabs if you copy/paste this)

```
SParse1

#  Append .custom.local to all incoming emails from 12.34.56.78
R$* < $* > $*                   $: $1 < $2 taglocal. $&{client_addr} .custom.local > $3     add IP into addresses
R$* < $* taglocal.12.34.56.78.custom.local > $* $: $1 < $2 custom.local > $3                    convert just this 1 IP we want
R$* < $* taglocal $* > $*               $: $1 < $2 > $4                         remove IP we added above
```

for those looking to explode their own brains - Parse1 is where recipient addresses (sanitized, and with "<" and ">" already added by earlier rules) get checked and used for stuff.  What we do, is add on whatever IP address arrived into the email address (a<@b.com.taglocal.192.168.0.2.custom.local>), then we change the one IP we are interested in to what we really want, then we remove anytihng that got added which we didn't want in the first place.

Yeah - weird - sendmail can't do simple ordinary "if/then", so we've got to tangle our heads with this dumb idea.  Whoever wrote that .cf / .mc stuff deserved a genius medal for the flexibility of it, then to be strangled with the same meddle for being stupid enough to write and release it.